# Does Inno Setup verysilent uninstallation option remove shared files?

Tags: inno-setup, uninstallation

The `/VERYSILENT` option offered by Inno Setup is very helpful when deploying applications to a whole organization using a centralized software, but there are some perks which are not entirely clear to me.

In particular, how does it behave when removing dlls/com controls (during an uninstallation) which need to be unregistered and are marked as sharedobject? Without the `/VERYSILENT` switch, a popup is shown, to allow the user to select whether those objects should be removed or not.

Is the default option (*"Yes"*, meaning "remove the object") used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the [`sharedfile`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=sharedfile) files are removed in silent and very silent uninstallations:

> 2021-01-04 11:42:56.253   Log opened. (Time zone: UTC+01:00)
> 2021-01-04 11:42:56.253   Setup version: Inno Setup version 6.1.2
> ...
> 2021-01-04 11:42:56.253   Uninstall command line: /SECONDPHASE="C:\Program Files (x86)\My Program\unins000.exe" /FIRSTPHASEWND=$530FFA /INITPROCWND=$461118 /log="B:\sharedo\uninstall.log" **/verysilent**
> ...
> 2021-01-04 11:42:56.284   Starting the uninstallation process.
> 2021-01-04 11:42:56.285   **Decrementing shared count (32-bit): C:\Program Files (x86)\My Program\MyDll.dll**
> 2021-01-04 11:42:56.285   **Shared count reached zero.**
> 2021-01-04 11:42:56.416   **Deleting file: C:\Program Files (x86)\My Program\MyDll.dll**
> 2021-01-04 11:42:56.416   Deleting directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\My Program
> 2021-01-04 11:42:56.955   Deleting directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\My Program
> 2021-01-04 11:42:56.986   Uninstallation process succeeded.
> 2021-01-04 11:42:56.986   Removed all? Yes
> 2021-01-04 11:42:56.986   Need to restart Windows? No
> 2021-01-04 11:42:56.988   Log closed.

---

Check also the [`TExtUninstallLog.ShouldRemoveSharedFile` function in Inno Setup source code](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-6_1_2/Projects/Uninstall.pas#L76-L81).